# After using If statement in Custom filter the page being redirected many times

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a company listing when there is no company listing I have to redirect the user to create a company. Without company, the application won't work so I added a global filter using If the Company does not exist but it is redirecting too many times so how to fix it can you help me

I have no solution. I have not tried anything.

```
public class CompanyExistsFilter: ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    [Authorize]
    void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var company = new ApplicationDbContext();
        if (company.globalCompany.Any())
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
            new RouteValueDictionary
            {
                { "Action", "Create" },
                { "Controller","GlobalCompany"}
            });


        }else
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);




    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that this is a global filter that executes for every page. If there is no company, it redirects to the `create company` page, and then the filter executes again and since there is still no company it keeps redirecting to the same page.

You need to exclude the `create company` page from the filter so the filter does not execute on that page.

Comment: how to exclude on the create company page

Comment: Bro I figured it myself;

Comment: you can add disable a property in the custom filter class and then you can add disable ==true in the controller this way you can stop continuous execution anyways thanks